# How to disable schema checking in FastAPI?

Tags: python, validation, schema, fastapi, pydantic

I am migrating a service from Flask to FastAPI and using Pydantic models to generate the documentation. However, I'm a little unsure about the schema check. I'm afraid there will be some unexpected data (like a different field format) and it will return an error.

In the Pydantic documentation there are ways to create a model without checking the schema: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#creating-models-without-validation

However, as this is apparently instantiated by FastAPI itself, I don't know how to disable this schema check when returning from FastAPI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could return [Response directly](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/), or with using [custom responses](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/) for automatic convertion. In this case, response data is not validated against the response model. But you can still document it as described in [Additional Responses in OpenAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/additional-responses/).

Example:

```
class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    num: int


@app.get("/get", response_model=SomeModel)
def handler(param: int):
    if param == 1:  # ok
        return {"num": "1"}
    elif param == 2:  # validation error
        return {"num": "not a number"}
    elif param == 3:  # ok (return without validation)
        return JSONResponse(content={"num": "not a number"})
    elif param == 4:  # ok (return without validation and conversion)
        return Response(content=json.dumps({"num": "not a number"}), media_type="application/json")
```

Comment: You could also use the `Any` type. See answer below.

Comment: If you do Any, it won't show the fields for OpenAPI documentation. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/#interactive-api-docs

Answer (score 1):

You can set the request model as a `typing.Dict` or `typing.List`

```py
from typing import Dict

app.post('/')
async def your_function(body: Dict):
  return { 'request_body': body}
```

Comment: If you do dict, it won't show the fields for OpenAPI documentation. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/#interactive-api-docs

Answer (score -1):

FastAPI doesn't enforce any kind of validation, so if you don't want it, simply do not use Pydantic models or type hints.

```py
app.get('/')
async def your_function(input_param):
  return { 'param': input_param }

# Don't use models or type hints when defining the function params.
# `input_param` can be anything, no validation will be performed.
```

However, as @Tryph rightly pointed out, since you're using Pydantic to generate the documentation, you could simply use the `Any` type like so:

```py
from typing import Any
from pydantic import BaseModel

class YourClass(BaseModel):
    any_value: Any
```

Beware that the `Any` type also accepts `None`, making in fact the field optional. (See also `typing.Any` in the Pydantic [docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/))

Comment: pydantic models are also used to generate the documentation.